# $x^3-y^2+ab=a-b(x+y)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

Is it possible to find the set of solutions for this equation?
I tried factorising but in vain: By adding and subtracting $x^2$ I get
$$\left(x+\frac{b}{2}\right)^2-\left(y-\frac{b}{2}\right)^2=-x^3+x^2+a-ab$$
$$(x+y)(x-y+b)=-x^3+x^2+a-ab$$

Comment: I suppose you could regard this as a quadratic equation in $y$ and solve for $y$ in terms of $x$. Then each $x$ would typically determine two values of $y$ so that $(x,y)$ is a solution.

Comment: What kind of numbers are you searching for?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner there should be positive integers solution of this

Comment: @MPW I don't see how it is possible to separate either from the other.

Comment: You can expand the right hand side

$$x^3-y^2+ab=a-bx-by$$

then move all terms to the left hand side

$$x^3-y^2+ab-a+bx+by=0 $$

where multiplying by $-1$

$$y^2-by-x^3-bx-ab+a=0$$

allows you to use the quadratic formula 

$$y=\frac{b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4(-x^3-bx-ab+a)}}{2}=\frac{b \pm \sqrt{b^2+4x^3+4bx+4ab-4a}}{2}$$

Comment: Alright, I see what @MPW meant, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some solutions $(a,b,x,y)$:

```
(-3, -3, 1, 2)
(-3, -7, 2, 2)
(-9, -13, 1, 6)
(-3, -13, 3, 2)
(-9, -19, 2, 6)
(-3, -21, 4, 2)
(-9, -27, 3, 6)
(-3, -31, 5, 2)
(-9, -37, 4, 6)
(-3, -43, 6, 2)
(-9, -49, 5, 6)
(-3, -57, 7, 2)
(-9, -63, 6, 6)
(-3, -73, 8, 2)
(-9, -79, 7, 6)
(-3, -91, 9, 2)
(-9, -97, 8, 6)
(-3, -111, 10, 2)
(-9, -117, 9, 6)
(-3, -133, 11, 2)
(-9, -139, 10, 6)
(-3, -157, 12, 2)
(-9, -163, 11, 6)
(-3, -183, 13, 2)
(-9, -189, 12, 6)

(5, 7, 3, 13)
(19, 79, 3, 97)
(29, 5, 5, 19)
(29, 13, 13, 59)
(41, 7, 7, 29)
(41, 13, 3, 31)
(41, 17, 7, 43)
(47, 3, 3, 13)
(71, 11, 13, 61)
(73, 3, 17, 73)
(97, 3, 11, 41)
(97, 13, 7, 47)
```